# What happens to the rest of an ArrayList once an object has been deleted within it?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

In Java, when you do this:

```
alist[0].remove();
```

What happens to the rest of the array list. Do all of the objects move up one or do they stay the same and there is just an empty index at [0]?

If not, is there an efficient way of moving each object's index closer down by one?

To clarify what I mean by more effecient:

You could just remove the first index and then iterate through the ArrayList and delete each object and re-assign it to a new index, but this seems very ineffecient and it seems like there should be a way but I have looked through at the [JavaDoc page for the ArrayList class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and do not see anything that would accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean `aList.remove(0)`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you actually meant to ask about `aList.remove(0)`...

As [documented by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29):

> public E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified
>   position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left
>   (subtracts one from their indices).

So `remove` does as you require. However, you may not consider the implementation efficient since it requires time proportional to the number of elements remaining in the list. For example, if you have a list with 1 million items in it and you remove the item at index 0, then the remaining 999,999 items will need to be moved in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the code you posted that is irrelevant to an `ArrayList`, if you were to look at the source for `ArrayList` you'd find that when calling `ArrayList.remove(obj)` it finds the index (or if using `remove(int)` it already knows) then does:

```
System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                          numMoved);
```

An `ArrayList` is backed by an array and it shifts everything in that backing array to the left.

In that case, the lookup is O(1) if you're using `remove(int)` or O(n) if providing an object, and the remove operation is O(n).

If you were to use a `LinkedList` the lookup is O(n) or O(n) but the removal is O(1) because it's a doubly-linked list.

When choosing a data structure, it's important to consider how you're going to be using it; there are always trade-offs depending on your use pattern.